# Заставить DIR-300 выдавать по DHCP другой шлюз

Tags: dhcp, lan, маршрутизация, windows-7

Ситуация такова: имеется локальная сеть организованная посредством маршрутизатора DIR-300 NRU, подключение к интернету идёт через USB-модем подключённый к одному из компьютеров(192.168.0.3).Вопрос: как заставить маршрутизатор выдавать через DHCP адрес настоящего шлюза, а не свой собственный(192.168.0.1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В штатной прошивке скорее всего ни как, а вот [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DNSMasq_as_DHCP_server#Assign_an_alternate_Gateway) поможет, если роутер поддерживается, смотрите таблицу совместимости на сайте dd-wrt